# How to transit html-code (with tags) throw 'data-title' to css content: attr(data-title)? Or some enother way

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I realised `hover tooltips` in my html code by bellow mechanism:

html (Django temlates):

```
          <div class="hint-quest-mark">
             &nbsp;?<span class="hint-title" data-title="{{ class_.explanation }}"></span>
          </div>
```

`class_.explanation` variable is string with \n for string breaks. But in browser it return:

```
      <div class="hint-quest-mark">
         &nbsp;?<span class="hint-title" data-title="string 1 string2 string3"></span>
      </div>
```

without **\n.** without **line breaks**

I can use django filter `linebreaksbr` that change '\n' to `<br>` tag, but css content: `attr(data-title)` can't use html tags and return `"string 1<br>string2<br>string3"`.

CSS:

```
.hint-title {
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
}
.hint-quest-mark:hover > .hint-title::after {
        display: block;
        content: attr(data-title);
        position: absolute;
        top: -24px;
        left: 27px;
        z-index: 1;

}
.hint-quest-mark:hover > .hint-title::before {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: url("pict/hint_left_oblique.png") no-repeat;
        content: "";
        left: 12px;
        top: -12px;
        z-index: 2;
}
```

The question is: how can i imlement some tags in css-content, or may be, some enother desision to realise self-made hover tooltips with content with html-tags in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-sigarette decision is reject `data-title -> content: attr(data-title)`method.

Beeter is to use `tiptool <div>` in html directly, without ::before/::after; and to swith it on/off by `Jquery` on hover.

```
    <div class="hint-quest-mark" 
             onmouseover="$(this).children('.hint-title-hover').css('display', 'block');
                          $(this).children('.hint-title-pin').css('display', 'block');"
                                                    
             onmouseleave="$(this).children('.hint-title-hover').css('display', 'none');
                           $(this).children('.hint-title-pin').css('display', 'none');">
    
                         &nbsp;?
                          <div class="hint-title-pin"></div>
                          <div class="hint-title-hover">
                           <span>{{ class_.explanation|linebreaksbr }}</span>
                          </div>
   </div>
```